# Binary operations with typed arrays

Tags: javascript, binary

I am trying to parse binary message.

I have made a function for getting short value, but this does not work when the second byte is negative.
For example:

```
function bytesToShort(arr, offset){
    return (arr[offset] << 8) | arr[offset + 1];
}

let binary = new Int8Array([3, -40]); // equals to 00000011 10101000
bytesToShort(binary, 0); // returns -40
// but 0b0000001110101000 = 936
```

Why I'm getting this result?? And how to change function for correct answer, without using Int16Array??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the core of the problem is that even though your typed array stores values in single bytes, when you retrieve them JS will convert them into 4-byte numbers that represent the same value, and perform the operations on those. If you want to retrieve multi-byte values from byte arrays, I'd recommend using a DataView:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView

In your example, this would be:

```
new DataView(arr.buffer).getInt16(0);
```

(note: there is a separate `getInt16()` and `getUInt16()` method, you'll have to decide which one works with your model)

Comment: Hmmm, `new DataView(new Int8Array([3, -40]).buffer).getInt16(0)` returns 984, its wrong too...

Comment: Your binary transcription of -40 is incorrect: you just took 40 (`0b00101000`) and set the highest bit to 1. Negative numbers in binary are represented in 2's complement form, which in the case of -40 is `0b11011000` (i.e. it's basically just 256 - 40 = 216 on 8 bits).

Comment: Oww, yes yes yes!! I am totally forgot about it, `(-40).toString(2)` confused me) Thank you for answer)